# How to have auto-correct QLineEdit when typing?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

How do I have a QLineEdit auto-correct when a key is typed? 
For this example, when you type the "<" I want it to auto-correct to "less than".

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # auto complete options                                                 
        names = ["Apple", "Alps", "Berry", "Cherry" ]
        completer = QCompleter(names)

        # create line edit and add auto complete                                
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit.setCompleter(completer)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From what I understand you, you want that if you type a key such as "<" then it must be replaced with another one, in this case "less than". I am right?

Comment: yes, I know there would be a keysequence in there too now that you mention it. Basically I need my GUI lineedit to replace  "<" to "less than" and " ' " for " ` "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a character was added and if so, replace the QLineEdit text. A possible implementation can be override the keyPressEvent method:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCompleter, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QWidget


class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, mapping, parent=None):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mapping = mapping

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        last_text = self.text()
        super(LineEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        new_text = self.text()
        if last_text + event.text() == new_text:
            new_text = self.mapping.get(event.text())
            if new_text is not None:
                self.setText(last_text + new_text)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)

        names = ["Apple", "Alps", "Berry", "Cherry"]
        completer = QCompleter(names)

        mapping = {"<": "less than", ">": "greater than", "'": "`"}
        self.lineedit = LineEdit(mapping)
        self.lineedit.setCompleter(completer)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: perfect answer, exactly what i needed

Comment: @spaceguy101 If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: I asked the same question but using QPlainTextEdit if you want to help with that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380082/how-do-i-have-a-qplaintextedit-auto-correct-when-a-key-is-typed-for-this-exampl